# How to delete all lines matching a pattern and a line after in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

There's a text

```
Title of the text

This line contains a word that is matched by the pattern and it should be deleted.
Next line is supposed to be deleted as well.

Loren ipsum dolorem...

This line contains a word that is matched by the pattern and it should be deleted.
And this one should be deleted

The end of the article
```

How to delete every pair of lines matching the first line, e.g. 'This line contains a word...' and the line after that one. Result would be:

```
Title of the text

Loren ipsum dolorem...

The end of the article
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use

```
:g/word/normal 2dd
```

This finds all instances of word and then executes the command after it. In this case it executes `2dd` in normal mode

Answer (score 35):

Use `:g[lobal]` with a `d[elete]` command with a `,+1` range to delete matched line and the next:

```
:g/word/,+1d
```

- [`:global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:global)
- [`:delete`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:delete)
- [command ranges](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#[range])

Comment: Another variant if you want to delete matching line and line before it, then use this: `:g/pattern/-1n,.d`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `:g[lobal]` command:

```
:g/This line/norm 3dd
```

Answer (score 3):

another way with :g

```
:g/word/norm dj
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try this:

```
:g/your pattern go here/d
```

Comment: While this line of code may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: This command only deletes matching line, but not the line after it. So, it does not answer the question.